# Using mesh analysis find all current

Tags: analysis, mesh-analysis

[image]

Using mesh analysis find all the current in the given circuit

Schematic redrawed:

[image]

Comment: could you do a non-rotated, not totally angled foto of your schematic, or even better yet, use the built-in schematic editor? Then, you also need to ask a specific **question**, which you seem to have forgotten. **Edit** your question to do so, don't do it here in the comments.

Comment: It is of little benefit for the community to collect theoretical problems and serial solutions. And we don't have fun doing other's people homework. Show at least significant own work to get help with your problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem with no attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing resistance value in your circuit.
provided that it has a given value :
there are two methods : 
the first one satisfies mesh analysis 
1 - apply superposition principle ( you can check this online).
2 - label the nodes dotted in the image and start your mesh analysis by substituting each current by ( v+ - v-) / R 
you'll end up with 4 eqns of 4 variables .

the second method doesn't give you the current in each resistor but will give you the total resistance and the total current
this way is called : delta to wye  transformation.[image]